# O que significa <<- em R?

Tags: r

O que significa o operador `<<-` em R, quais são suas diferenças com relação a `<-` e em que circunstâncias ele pode ser útil?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Vou explicar com um exemplo.

```
> objeto_fora_da_funcao <- 1
> f <- function() {
    objeto_fora_da_funcao <- 10
    return(objeto_fora_da_funcao)
}
```

Saídas

```
> f()
# [1] 10

> objeto_fora_da_funcao
# [1] 1
```

Agora, vamos mudar `<-` por `<<-` dentro da função `f`:

```
> objeto_fora_da_funcao <- 1
> f <- function() {
    objeto_fora_da_funcao <<- 10
    return(objeto_fora_da_funcao)
}
```

Repare nas saídas agora:

Saídas

```
> objeto_fora_da_funcao
# [1] 1

> f()
# [1] 10

> objeto_fora_da_funcao
# [1] 10
```

O que está por trás disso é o jeito que o R guarda os objetos em "environments", que poderia ser visto como conjuntos de objetos (números, vetores, data.frames, funções, etc.).

`<<-` é geralmente útil dentro de funções, pois as funções trabalham com "environments" próprios, temporários. Apesar das funções de acessarem objetos globais, o operador `<-` está programado para criar (ou redefinir) objetos dentro do "environment" da respectiva função, apenas. E é exatamente por isso que existe o `<<-`. Ele irá procurar objetos com aquele dado nome em todos os "environments" do mais específico até o mais abrangente (conhecido como "Global environment").

Isso é útil quando vc quer que uma função altere variáveis globais.

Comment: Só que alterar variáveis globais de dentro de uma função vão contra as boas práticas de programação da maioria das linguagens modernas :P

Comment: @LucasSoares É que a principal vantagem não é necessariamente alterar as variáveis globais, mas sim as variáveis dentro do próprio ambiente da função, vou colocar um exemplo.

Comment: Athos, eu somente alteraria a última frase para: "Isso é útil quando vc quer que uma função altere variáveis **de seu ambiente pai**." Abraços!

Comment: @Athos, continua sendo uma violação das boas práticas. Para facilitar o entendimento do código, a localização de bugs e uma eventual paralelização, o ideal é que cada função altere apenas o seu ambiente.

Answer (score 6):

Complementando a resposta do Athos, seguem alguns exemplos em que o uso do `<<-` pode ser útil para alterar variáveis dentro do próprio ambiente da função sem alterar variáveis globais:

Gerando um contador que acumula o valor de `i` no ambiente da função [(baseado no livro do Hadley):](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#closures)

```
contador <- function() {
  i <- 0
  function() {
    i <<- i + 1
    i
  }
}

cont1 <- contador()
cont1()
[1] 1
cont1()
[1] 2
cont1()
[1] 3
cont2 <- contador()
cont2() # note que o contador de cont2 é separdo de cont1
[1] 1
cont1()
[1] 4
```

Implementando *memoization* com `local` e `<<-` na sequência de fibonacci [(exemplo adaptado do R Inferno)](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf):

```
fibonacci <- local({
  memo <- c(0, 1, rep(NA, 100))
  f <- function(x) {
    if(x == 0) return(0)
    if(x < 0) return(NA)
    if(x > length(memo))
      stop("’x’ too big for implementation")
    if(!is.na(memo[x])) return(memo[x])
    ans <- f(x-2) + f(x-1)
    memo[x] <<- ans
    ans
  }
})
fibonacci(10)
[1] 34
```

Gerando uma seqüência de fibonacci com `replicate` e `<<-`

```
fibonacci <- function(n){
  x0 <- 0
  x1 <- 1
  x <- numeric() # para assegurar que <<- não altere a variável global
  fib <- function(){x <<- x1 + x0; x0 <<- x1; x1 <<- x}
  c(x0, x1, replicate(n-2, fib()))
}

fibonacci(10)
[1]  0  1  1  2  3  5  8 13 21 34
```